# How should I test React Hook "useEffect" making an api call with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, axios, enzyme, react-hooks

I'm writing some jest-enzyme tests for a simple React app using Typescript and the new React hooks.

However, I can't seem to properly simulate the api call being made inside the `useEffect` hook.

`useEffect` makes the api call and updates the `useState` state "data" with "setData".

The object "data" is then mapped into a table to its corresponding table cells.

This seems like it should be easy to tackle with a mocked api response and an enzyme mount, but I keep getting errors telling me to use `act()` for component updates.

I tried using `act()` many ways but to no avail. I've tried replacing `axios` with fetch and using enzyme shallow and the react-test-library's render, but nothing seems to work.

**The component:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface ISUB {
  id: number;
  mediaType: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  monthlyPayment: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  singleIssue: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  subscription: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  title: string;
}

interface IDATA extends Array<ISUB> {}

const initData: IDATA = [];

const SalesPlanTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initData);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`/path/to/api`)
      .then(res => {
        setData(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  const renderTableRows = () => {
    return data.map((i: ISUB, k: number) => (
      <tr key={k}>
        <td>{i.id}</td>
        <td>
          {i.title}
        </td>
        <td>
          {i.subscription.print}
          {i.mediaType.digital}
        </td>
        <td>
          {i.monthlyPayment.print}
          {i.monthlyPayment.digital}
        </td>
        <td>
          {i.singleIssue.print}
          {i.singleIssue.digital}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>MediaType</th>
          <th>MonthlyPayment</th>
          <th>SingleIssue</th>
          <th/>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody'>{renderTableRows()}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default SalesPlanTable;
```

**The test:**

```
const response = {
  data: {
    results: [
      {
        id: 249,
        mediaType: {
          digital: true,
          print: true
        },
        monthlyPayment: {
          digital: true,
          print: true
        },
        singleIssue: {
          digital: true,
          print: true
        },
        subscription: {
          digital: true,
          print: true
        },
        title: 'ELLE'
      }
    ]
  }
};

//after describe

it('should render a proper table data', () => {
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    mock.onGet('/path/to/api').reply(200, response.data);
    act(() => {
      component = mount(<SalesPlanTable />);
    })
    console.log(component.debug())
  });
```

I expect it to log the html of the table with the table body section rendered, I tried some async and different ways to mock `axios` but I keep either getting just the table headers or the message: An update to `SalesPlanTable` inside a test was not wrapped in `act(...).` I looked for many hours for a resolution but can't find anything that works so I decided to muster up some courage and ask here.

Comment: `so I decided to muster up some courage and ask here` ...we're not THAT scary, are we?  :)  (great question, btw)

Comment: Haha I asked something on here a while back but I was way less experienced with javascript and didn't thoroughly search on here before asking so it got taken down immediately :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two issues at play here

---

### Asynchronous call to `setData`

`setData` gets called in a `Promise` callback.

As soon as a `Promise` resolves, any callbacks waiting for it get queued in the [PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues).  Any pending jobs in the PromiseJobs queue run *after the current message has completed and before the next one begins*.

In this case the currently running message is your test so your test completes before the `Promise` callback has a chance to run and `setData` isn't called until **after** your test completes.

You can fix this by using something like `setImmediate` to delay your assertions until after the callbacks in PromiseJobs have a chance to run.

Looks like you'll also need to call `component.update()` to re-render the component with the new state.  (I'm guessing this is because the state change happens outside of an `act` since there isn't any way to wrap that callback code in an `act`.)

All together, the working test looks like this:

```
it('should render a proper table data', done => {
  const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
  mock.onGet('/path/to/api').reply(200, response.data);
  const component = mount(<SalesPlanTable />);
  setImmediate(() => {
    component.update();
    console.log(component.debug());
    done();
  });
});
```

---

### Warning: An update to ... was not wrapped in act(...)

The warning is triggered by state updates to the component that happen outside of an `act`.

State changes caused by **asynchronous calls to `setData` triggered by a `useEffect` function** will always happen outside of an `act`.

Here is an extremely simple test that demonstrates this behavior:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

const SimpleComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('initial');

  useEffect(() => {
    setImmediate(() => setData('updated'));
  }, []);

  return (<div>{data}</div>);
};

test('SimpleComponent', done => {
  const wrapper = mount(<SimpleComponent/>);
  setImmediate(done);
});
```

As I was searching for more info I stumbled on [`enzyme` issue #2073](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2073) opened just 10 hours ago talking about this same behavior.

I added the above test [in a comment](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2073#issuecomment-477423695) to help the `enzyme` devs address the issue.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! It still has the weird 'act()' warning like you said but the table actually renders the proper data now, which is all I need... Hats off to you, sir!

Comment: Use `jest.useFakeTimers` and wrap `jest.runAllImmediates` in `act`. This way there is no more error: https://github.com/eps1lon/react-act-immediate/blob/4d61b67dc98dd8dd422a41d07b82e08a8031bded/src/index.test.js. I could not solve the original issue with this method though.

Comment: Test passes, but still getting `Warning: An update to Post inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`

Comment: I was able to remove the warning by wrapping the setImmediate in an `act` like so: ```await act(() => new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      node.update();
      resolve();
    });
  }))```

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

It both **works** and **gets rid** of the `test was not wrapped in act(...)` warning.

```
const waitForComponentToPaint = async (wrapper) => {
   await act(async () => {
     await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
     wrapper.update();
   });
};
```

Usage:

```
it('should do something', () => {
    const wrapper  = mount(<MyComponent ... />);
    await waitForComponentToPaint(wrapper);
    expect(wrapper).toBlah...
})
```

### Thanks to...

This is a work-around suggested by **edpark11** in the [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2073) @Brian_Adams mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55389616/5552686).

Original post: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2073#issuecomment-565736674

I copied the post here with a few modifications for archiving sake.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad practice to mock the library used to make fetch requests. Say you want to replace axios with fetch or isomorphic-unfetch? You would have to completely replace all of the mocks in your test suite with a new one. It's better to bind your tests to the server contracts than the mocks.

Use a server stub library like [msw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msw) or [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) + [React Testing Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react) (RTL). RTL has some great tools to kick over React's lifecycle on asynchronous executions.

Here's how I would re-write the test using the example you provided:

### RTL + Nock

```js
/* SalesPlanTable.jsx */

import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface ISUB {
  id: number;
  mediaType: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  monthlyPayment: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  singleIssue: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  subscription: {
    digital: boolean;
    print: boolean;
  };
  title: string;
}

interface IDATA extends Array<ISUB> {}

const initData: IDATA = [];

const SalesPlanTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initData);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('loading');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/path/to/api');
        setData(response.data.results);
        setStatus('ready');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setStatus('error');
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const renderTableRows = () => {
    return data.map((i: ISUB, k: number) => (
      <tr key={k}>
        <td>{i.id}</td>
        <td>{i.title}</td>
        <td>
          {i.subscription.print}
          {i.mediaType.digital}
        </td>
        <td>
          {i.monthlyPayment.print}
          {i.monthlyPayment.digital}
        </td>
        <td>
          {i.singleIssue.print}
          {i.singleIssue.digital}
        </td>
        <td>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };

  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (status === 'error') {
    return <div>Error occurred while fetching data.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>MediaType</th>
          <th>MonthlyPayment</th>
          <th>SingleIssue</th>
          <th />
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{renderTableRows()}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default SalesPlanTable;
```

```js
/* SalesPlanTable.test.jsx */

import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import nock from 'nock';

import SalesPlanTable from './SalesPlanTable';

/**
 * @NOTE: This should probably go into a `__fixtures__` folder.
 */
const response = {
  data: {
    results: [
      {
        id: 249,
        mediaType: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        monthlyPayment: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        singleIssue: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        subscription: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        title: 'ELLE',
      },
    ],
  },
};

describe('<SalesPlanTable />', () => {
  it('displays the title', async () => {
    const scope = nock('http://localhost')
      .get('/path/to/api')
      .reply(200, response.data);

    render(<SalesPlanTable />);
  
    // Wait for the async task to kick over
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  
    // Test the render
    expect(screen.getByText('ELLE')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(scope.isDone()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

### Enzyme + Nock

```
/* SalesPlanTable.jsx */

import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import nock from 'nock';

import SalesPlanTable from './SalesPlanTable';

const response = {
  data: {
    results: [
      {
        id: 249,
        mediaType: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        monthlyPayment: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        singleIssue: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        subscription: {
          digital: true,
          print: true,
        },
        title: 'ELLE',
      },
    ],
  },
};

describe('<SalesPlanTable />', () => {
  it('displays the title', async () => {
    nock('http://localhost')
      .get('/path/to/api')
      .reply(200, response.data);

    const component = mount(<SalesPlanTable />);
    
    // Wait for API call to complete
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve)); 
    component.update();

    expect(component.find('td').at(1).text()).toBe('ELLE');
    expect(scope.isDone()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```