# React (v16.14.0) Testing w/ Enzyme/Jest: Component state rendering data on fetch that is inside a useEffect

Tags: enzyme, ts-jest, react-tsx, jest-enzyme

I am having issue with testing a component that makes a fetch call inside a `useEffect`. What's happening is that, state is being updated but the component is not rendering the data from the fetch call that was set via the `useEffect`. It works fine the application is running, just not in the context of testing. Example below.

Functional Component

```js
export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]); // <-- assume this is a list/array of numbers 1-20

    useEffect(() => {
       fetchData().then((response) => {
           setData(response)
       });
    }, []);

    return (
      <div id="the-data-list">
          { data?.length > 0 && data?.map((d) => (<span id=`the-data-${d}`>{ d }</span>)) }
      </div>
    );
}
```

Test Suite

```js
describe('My Component Test Suite', () => {
    
    component = mount(<MyComponent />);

    it('should render the data', () => {
       const theData = component.find("#the-data-1").first();

       console.log(theData); <-- data is not rendered
    });

})
```

Odd thing is, putting a `console.log` right under where data is defined I can see that on the first render it's an empty []. On second render it has the data, but the data isn't rendered in the view. Any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Enzyme versions:

- enzyme: 3.11.0
- enzyme-adapter-react-16: 1.15.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388587/how-should-i-test-react-hook-useeffect-making-an-api-call-with-typescript

Comment: Hi! This did not work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out one of the reason why this didn't work for me is that the test data I was using was incorrect. It was an object instead of an array of object smh. I also added the usage of `async` and `await`. Below is the re-work of the example unit test suite.

```js
describe('My Component Test Suite', () => {
    
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await act(async () => {
            component = mount(<MyComponent />);
        });
    });
    
    it('should render the data', async () => {
       const theData = component.find("#the-data-1").first();

       console.log(theData.debug()); <-- html is now rendered!!
    });
})
```